# Document Term Matrix will not maintain decimal places of numbers

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus, term-document-matrix

Before I updated my version of RStudio, everything worked great. With the update something has changed with Document Term Matrix in the 'tm' package. I want to create a dtm, but with numbers. For instance if I have a .csv with one column as shown below:

```
x
1.01
11.21
123.35
212.11
```

I want the column names in my term matrix to look like this:

```
1.01 11.21 123.35 212.11
1    0     0      0
0    1     0      0
0    0     1      0
0    0     0      1
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
123 212
0   0
0   0
1   0
0   1
```

Here's the code that used to work:

`corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(x))
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm_df = as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))`

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version do you have? I have Version 1.0.136 and it seems to be working as you had hoped.

Comment: I have 1.0.136 as well.....

Comment: Actually the results are: `123 212` as the column names. Not `1 11 123 212` as mention previously @Lucy

Comment: I have tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling, tried older versions (Studio 0.99.489 & R 3.3.1), but I get the same results. I ask others to test it out and it works for them. Also, I had someone download R, Rtools, and RStudio to test this and they got the same results I did. I have no idea what has happened and would greatly appreciate help on this matter as it is extremely urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 'tm' package maintainer Ingo Feinerer:

Here's the code that used to work:

corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(x))

> Try VCorpus() instead of Corpus().

dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm_df = as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))

> That is highly inefficient (since as.matrix() generates a dense representation from the sparse term-document matrix).

Best regards,
Ingo